# Удаление дубликатов в 2х файлах (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Есть два файла, пусть в Эксель: `old.xlsx` и `new.xlsx`.

Выглядят одинаково. Все поля текстовые, `id` уникальный.

**old.xlsx:**

```
id компании     Название    Адрес
123             Ромашка     Ленина 23
124             Лютик       Свердлова 14
122             Роза        Цветочная 10
```

**new.xlsx:**

```
id компании     Название    Адрес
123             Ромашка     Ленина 23
124             Лютик       Свердлова 14
127             Каштан      Лесная 12
```

Требуется сверить `new.xlsx` с `old.xlsx` по `id компании`, так, чтобы в результате получились только новые, относительно `old.xlsx`, строки.

В приведённом выше примере должно остаться:

```
127             Каштан      Лесная 12
```

(все остальные строки удалены,

```
122             Роза        Цветочная 10
```

тоже не сохраняется, так как содержится в старом файле).

Делаю так (с использованием `openpyxl`):

```
import openpyxl

wbo = openpyxl.load_workbook('old.xlsx')
wbn = openpyxl.load_workbook('new.xlsx')

wso = wbo.active
wsn = wbn.active

row_old = wso["A"] # т.к. айдишник в столбце А
row_new = wsn["A"] 


for _io in row_old:
    cello = _io.value
        for _in in row_new:
            celln = _in.value
            if cello == celln:
            wsn.delete_rows(idx = _in)

wbn.save("output1.xlsx")
```

Вопрос1: как правильно написать синтаксис, логически вроде всё верно. Сейчас получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Cell' and 'int'

Вопрос2: так как файлы на самом деле весьма тяжелые, нет ли способа сделать то же самое с помощью `pandas` (она вроде по резвее будет).
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Приведи код в нормальный вид. В какой строке ошибка? В этом коде нет сравнения >, так что ошибка не отсюда.

Comment: Ошибка выглядит так:
File ".\sverka.py", line 18, in <module>
    wsn.delete_rows(idx = _in, amount=1)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 710, in delete_rows
    remainder = _gutter(idx, amount, self.max_row)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 881, in _gutter
    gutter = range(max(max_val+1-offset, idx), min(idx+offset, max_val)+1)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Cell' and 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В pandas:

Ваши таблицы (загружены методом `pd.read_excel()`):

```
In[1]: old
```

> ```
>    id компании Название         Адрес
> 0          123  Ромашка     Ленина 23
> 1          124    Лютик  Свердлова 14
> 2          122     Роза  Цветочная 10
> ```

```
In[2]: new
```

> ```
>    id компании Название         Адрес
> 0          123  Ромашка     Ленина 23
> 1          124    Лютик  Свердлова 14
> 2          127   Каштан     Лесная 12
> ```

Заменим их индексы (когда это нужно — может быть, что вы в методе `pd.read_excel()` применили параметр `index_col="id компании"`, получая тот же самый результат):

```
In[3]: old = old.set_index("id компании")
In[4]: new = new.set_index("id компании")
```

... и проверим результаты:

```
In[5]: old
```

> ```
>             Название         Адрес
> id компании                       
> 123          Ромашка     Ленина 23
> 124            Лютик  Свердлова 14
> 122             Роза  Цветочная 10
> ```

```
In[6]: new
```

> ```
>             Название         Адрес
> id компании                       
> 123          Ромашка     Ленина 23
> 124            Лютик  Свердлова 14
> 127           Каштан     Лесная 12
> ```

Сделаем математическую разность между множествами индексов и применим ею к новой таблице

```
In[7]: dif = new.reindex(new.index.difference(old.index))
```

... и проверим конечный результат:

```
In[8]: dif
```

> ```
>             Название      Адрес
> id компании                    
> 127           Каштан  Лесная 12
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

```
In[3]: old = old.set_index("id компании")
In[4]: new = new.set_index("id компании")
```

Эти команды заменят индекс (имя строк) на `"id компании"` (вместо стандартного `0`, `1`, `2`)

```
In[7]: dif = new.reindex(new.index.difference(old.index))
```

- `new.index.difference(old.index)` то же самое как `set(new.index) - set(old.index)` есть математическая разность между множествами значений индексов новой и старой таблицы — точно то, что вы хотите:

  `{123, 124, 127} - {123, 124, 122}` есть `{127}` (множество всех элементов *первого* множества, которые *не находятся во втором множестве*).
- Метод `reindex()` применит эту разность к новой таблице, устраняя таким образом все строки из старой таблицы.

Comment: «гранд мерси!​» - не стоит, но здесь бытует обычай выразить благодарность (тоже) **принятием ответа** (клик на галочку у начала ответа) и **голосованием за** (клик на верхний треугольник).

Comment: MarianD спасибо за совет, сделал как сказал. Я пока новенький, обживаюсь :)
1) А если "id компании" не int, а str?
2) Если всё-же среди "id компании" затешутся дубли, то drop_duplicates?

Comment: 1) это безразлично, будет работать так как написал, 2) не надо, т.к. применяется операция с множествами, которые автоматически выбросят дубликаты.

Comment: Не взлетает... 2 ошибки.
1) При добавлении буквы в ячейку "id компании" - вылезает ошибка:

    ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Удаляю дубли через:
    dfn.drop_duplicates(subset = "id компании", inplace=True)
    dfo.drop_duplicates(subset = "id компании", inplace=True)
Всё начинает работать в Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: 2) Но!

Как только переношу в код обработки (питоновский файл), ловим вот такую ошибку.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sverka.py", line 8, in <module>
    dfo.drop_duplicates(subset = "id компании", inplace=True)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4909, in drop_duplicates
    duplicated = self.duplicated(subset, keep=keep)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4966, in duplicated
    raise KeyError(diff)
KeyError: Index(['id компании'], dtype='object')

Comment: Мой ответ на ваш вопрос был правильным и я тратил достаточно времени что бы вам помог. В вашем вопросе вы сказали, что `id` уникальным и в примерах был тоже численным. - Пока вы думаете, что я обязан отвечать на ваше изменения оригинального вопроса в комментариях, иначе вы отмените принятие моего вопроса, это неправильный подход. Нужно написать другой вопрос.